# Help; how use Persistent Sets of Completion Candidates for search?

Tags: completion, find-file, icicles, filenames

I want to use a set of files inside my directory `~/Dokumente` to search for changes in title, content.  So I saved such a set of file names persistently, using `C-}` during file-name completion with Icicles.

Later, I can use `C-{` to restore that set of file names as completion candidates for a command that prompts for a file name.

But how can I combine this with command `icicle-locate` (or another command that prompts for a file name)?

Command `icicle-locate` can used with `C-M-j` to filter by both file name AND file content.  How can I do that and also take advantage of my saved persistent set of file names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for using command `icicle-find-file-absolute`, which is similar in most regards to `icicle-locate`.

But `icicle-locate` uses a prefix arg differently, passing it to system-command `locate`.  So `icicle-locate` doesn't handle the use of a prefix arg to make multi-completion candidates include also a last modification-date middle component.
(Command `icicle-locate-file` is more similar to `icicle-find-file-absolute` than is `icicle-locate`, which uses system command `locate`.)

The short, tl;dr, answer to your question is that even when completing to match both file name and file content, the completion candidates shown in `*Completions*` are just the file names, and it is perfectly OK to use `C-{` to retrieve a set of these.

---

1. (You already did this.) Use **`C-}`** during file-name completion, to save the file names that match your minibuffer pattern persistently.  Let's say you saved this in file `foo.el`, using name set-name `foo`.
2. `M-x icicle-find-file-absolute` (or just `C-u C-x C-f`).
3. At the prompt for a file name, use **`C-{`**, to restore your saved set of file names.  At the prompt, enter the name of the saved set, `foo`.  The saved names are shown as the completion candidates in buffer `*Completions*`.
4. Type **`C-M-j`**, to say that you are done matching file names and you now want to give a pattern to match file content.
5. Type a pattern to match file content, e.g., `toto.*titi`.  Use `S-TAB` to update `*Completions*`, to show only the names of files whose content matches regexp `toto.*titi`.

---

If you want to match also the file last-modification dates, then use a negative prefix arg.  In that case, after step 3, use **`C-M-j`** and type a pattern that matches the dates you want, then continue with step 4 (a second `C-M-j` followed by a file-content pattern).

---

As mentioned, `icicle-locate` is a bit different, because for it the prefix arg is passed to `locate`, so you can't use it to include last modification-date matching. But the general approach is the same.

---

See also:

- [Icicles - Multi-Completions](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions), for info about matching multi-completion candidates, that is, candidates that have multiple parts (such as file name and file content).
- [Icicles - File-Name Input](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input), for input about Icicles commands, such as those mentioned in this answer, which match absolute file names.
- [Icicles - Persistent Completions](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Persistent_Completions), for info about saving and restoring persistent sets of completion candidates.

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it seems, that i'm a little bit too stupid for that. After Step 3 i dont see a Completion Buffer. My Minibuffer shows "File or dir (absolute) (./)". Then i push C-M-j and .* to show all content. S-TAB brings up the Completion Buffer. Unfortunately with files from my home directory. And after a short time emacs complains "Reverting buffer ‘.xsession-errors’."
So it seems that i have to switch to the directory i saved. I thought, that the Completions are ONLY from the persistent set.

Comment: (1) #3 means: at the prompt `File or dir (absolute)`, use `C-{`. You should see `*Completions*` with your saved candidates at that point. (2) There's no sense in a content-matching regexp of `.*` Content-matching is optional - you need not use `C-M-j` at all, if you aren't filtering the candidate files by content (`.*` does no 
real filtering, because it matches all lines of content). (3) The file-name matching for this is *absolute* name matching. It's up to you to get the directory-matching part right, with your filename input pattern.